# GeoServer Data Security access rule implementation to single workspace & inside layers

Tags: geoserver, geoserver-security

I am using GeoServer 2.18.0 war file under Tomcat 9.0, and it's deployed on CentOS

**What I am doing :** Implementing data security rules for one workspace and layers belongs to that workspace.

**What's challenge is facing :** All data security rules not implementing to all layers inside that workspace. If I assign rules to each and every service then it's working, but in the bulk layers it's not implementing (might be the bug)

I am applying this rule, saving the changes but still it's not reflecting to all layers. Let's say if I have 200 layers under single workspace then it's very difficult to apply settings using manually

Links I followed :

https://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/security/layer.html

https://docs.geoserver.geo-solutions.it/edu/en/security/layer_level.html

https://medium.com/random-gis-talks/easiest-way-to-secure-data-in-geoserver-39cb0bb8c854

**Update :**

- Tested on Geoserver 2.20 version, facing same issue
- Permissions are not applying to Geoserver layers

[image: data security rule for all layers under sf workspace]

[image: data security rules not reflecting to its layers]

Comment: is the access not applied? or just doesn't show up in the layers view?

Comment: @IanTurton : Access not applied

Comment: are you sure you want to give anonymous users the ability to delete your data?